# Flexbox Grid with Images - Maintain Aspect Ratio / Proportions

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to use flexbox to layout something like the following:

```
 -- ------ --
|  |      |  |
|--|      |--|
|  |      |  |
 -- ------ --
```

Each corner 'box' has an img within it who's aspect ratio is 1:1 (square). The center 'box' is 3:2.

The problem is for whatever reason the height of the corner boxes and the center box is larger than the hight of the responsive img within it, I'm trying to get them to align perfectly.

How can I get the flex items to line up correctly?

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/codybarr/pen/zNgpVK

EDIT: adding `display: flex` to `.container .item` fixed the issue in Firefox but not Chrome/Safari. Now the images stretch to be their full resolution height..weird...

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: orange;
  }
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .container.second-column {
    flex: 1 0 60%;
  }
  .container .item {
    display: flex;
  }
  .container.second-column .item {}
  .container.first-column .item:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .container.first-column .item:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .container.third-column .item:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .container.third-column .item:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Flex Testing</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Flex Test!</h1>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container first-column">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/article/90741-image/Google-touts-advanced-recipe-search-in-mobile-app.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-cigJW9TQSRU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABg/Pg3e9ogcsHU/s640/photo.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container second-column">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.inetsolutions.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Capital-Letters-in-URLs-Do-Not-Influence-Google-Rankings.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container third-column">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.sociallyawareblog.com/files/2016/12/GettyImages-610773752_small.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/b1/e2/db/b1e2dbe6c6b547a2ebc53a49fc3ffa8c.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An initial setting of a flex container is `align-items: stretch`. This means that flex items will expand, by default, to cover the full length of the cross axis of the container.

Consider overriding the default with `align-items: flex-start`.

```
 container .item {
   display: flex;
   align-items: flex-start; /* new */
 }
```

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgobbP)

Comment: This seems to do the trick for Chrome/Safari! Thanks so much!